# Internet Dongle Help Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: networking, mobile-broadband, dongle

I have a 3Gmobile broadband dongle that is supposed to go on windows XP, Vista, and 7. Is there any way i can use this dongle for ubuntu 12.04? Model #- SCT-UM300

Comment: what is the model of the dongle?

Comment: What is the *purpose* of the dongle?

Comment: Did you ever try it on Ubuntu ? If yes, what happened ? After you plug the dongle, you can do `dmesg` to see if there is kernel messages related to it or not.

Comment: yes ive tried it on ubuntu, the dongles led light blinked and nothing happened

Comment: Hi Tyler, please make sure that the title of your post makes your subject searchable for other users who might have a similar question.

Comment: What is the result of `sudo lsusb -v` with the device plugged in?

Comment: Elliott, its asking me for a sudo password... what is this

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to install **usb-modeswitch** and **usb-modeswitch-data** packages, and to do that you have to use your Ubuntu CD/DVD as a repository, meaning you have to add it to the Software Sources list. Unless you also have a wired connection and you can already use the Internet. Anyway, you have to type this code in terminal:

```
  sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data
```

Those 2 packages should be already present on your system and you may get a message in the terminal saying that they are installed but if they are not you need them.

Next step is to visit [this page](http://linuxforums.org.uk/linux-tips-tricks/setting-up-a-3g-dongle-from-the-ubuntu-network-manager/) to learn how to setup a 3g connection using ubuntu network manager. I hope this helps because I am no expert in this kind of problems but I thought you can find a solution following the instructions from the link I gave you.

The intructions are targeted to people living in the UK, so you should choose your own location and all the other required data.